# Build target tools path

Tags: msbuild, nuget, msbuild-target

I am currently packaging a nuget package for my [code generator project](https://github.com/Toxantron/CGbR) and I have gotten so far as to include an executable into the `tools` directory and a build target into the process.

Partial from the nuspec

```
<files>
    <file src="cgbr.targets" target="build\cgbr.targets" />
    <file src="cgbr.json" target="content\cgbr.json" />
    <file src="..\bin\CGbR.Lib.dll" target="lib\CGbR.Lib.dll" />
    <file src="..\bin\cgbr.exe" target="tools\cgbr.exe" />
</files>
```

Content of the `cgbr.targets` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <Exec Command="cgbr.exe $(ProjectDir)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Now when I install the package I see that it is included into the build process. Unfortunately the path to `cgbr.exe` is invalid and I am a little stuck. Of course I could use `$(SolutionDir)packages\CGbR.0.3\tools\cgbr.exe` but than I would have to modify it every time I change the version.

To clarify: I need the path to my packages tools path.

**Edit:** Found a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868812/how-can-i-find-executables-installed-by-nuget-packages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a relative path to the tool from the targets file. There are a number of [predefined properties in msbuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx). Perhaps the most useful for these scenarios is `MSBuildThisFileDirectory` which returns the full path to the directory of the current proj file. An example:

```
<Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\cgbr.exe&quot; &quot;$(ProjectDir)&quot;"/>
```

Comment: Relative path is good, but I need a relative path to my nuget package directory.

Comment: @Toxantron Right but there isn't a notion of "my nuget package directory" in msbuild. There is however something for the current file's location, which is inside your nuget package directory. If your proj file is in package's "build" directory then the nuget package's directory is "$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory).." and you can find anything from there.